# Using integers as key in map which has enum key

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, enums, key

```
 enum aaa {a, b, c};

 std::map <aaa, int> container;

 container[0]; //compilation error
```

I know that in this case container is empty and I would get segfault, but that's not the problem. Enum is arithmetic type so why there is a problem?

Comment: A simple cast would solve the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're wrong on both counts. :)

An `int` is not implicitly convertible to an `enum`, **an explicit cast is required**, and you wouldn't get a segfault, because `container[0]` would value-initialize a new value in the map.

Comment: I see. So only enum can be implicitly converted to int, not the other way around.

Comment: @user1873947 yes. Type-safety ftw. The compiler forces you to think twice, and that's a good thing. What if your `int` can't be casted to that enum? What if you say `container[42]`?

Answer (score 1):

The key type of the container is `aaa`. The type of `0` is `int`. `int` is not implicitly convertible to `aaa`, therefore you get a compiler error.

Comment: can static_cast help there?

Comment: Yes. Except that if you want to index using `int`s, why not make it a `map<int, int>` in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Compiler expects the key to be of type `aaa`. So you need to write `container[a]` instead of what you do.